# Why does this perl script give different results from git-for-windows vs. windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: bash, perl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting different results when executing the same perl script via git-for-windows vs. via Windows Scripting Host (from a VBA module).

The perl command is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\bxlYes\b([^(\n|\r|\x27]*)/1$1 \x271=xlYes;/' -- *.*
```

and its purpose is to replace a given constant with its long value, and then append an informative comment.

The above command executes perfectly from git-for-windows. For example, this line code:

```
Set ListObject = Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
```

...(correctly) becomes this:

```
Set ListObject = Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , 1) '1=xlYes;
```

When executing the same command via the Windows Scripting Host (from VBA), I need to wrap the command as follows:

```
bash -c "perl -pi -e 's/\bxlYes\b([^(\n|\r|\x27]*)/1$1 \x271=xlYes;/' -- *.*"
```

And yet, when I do, the same line of code:

```
Set ListObject = Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
```

...(incorrectly) becomes this:

```
Set ListObject = Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , 1 '1=xlYes;
```

(note the missing right-parenthesis).

Could it be a version issue?

---

<sup>git-for-windows: bash version 4.4.23(1)-release; perl v5.30.2</sup>
<sup>windows subsystem for linux: bash version 4.4.20(1)-release; perl v5.26.1</sup>

(Please forgive me if this is not the right forum for this question.)

Comment: That's a weird regular expression. Why do you have two pipes in it?

Comment: have a look at the characterset [^(\n|\r|\x27]. I think you need [^\n\r\x27], but there is something wrong with the ( in the character set. You should debug it first.

Comment: @D.SM - I'm still learning regex, but the point there was to exclude either new line OR carriage return OR an apostrophe from the capturing group.

Comment: You are using a character class (`[abc]`, in your case a negated one `[^abc]`) which permits every character to be matched in any position. The pipes you've added and the opening parenthesis  are considered as  the allowed characters along with newlines and the quote.

Comment: Since bash -c "......" is enrobed in double quotes so you need to escape the $1 of the perl code. OTW it will be taking that as a blank(unless, horror of horrors, its set and you will see strange output). It's a problem of quoting. Better to interchange your single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @ruud - it should be `[^\n\r\x27]` instead of `[^(\n|\r|\x27]`

Kudos to @Rakesh Sharma - escaping the `$1` in the double-quoted wrapper did the trick.

raw:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\bxlYes\b([^\n\r\x27]*)/1$1 \x271=xlYes/' -- basAggregate.bas
```

with wrapper:

```
bash -c "perl -pi -e 's/\bxlYes\b([^\n\r\x27]*)/1\$1 \x271=xlYes/' -- basAggregate.bas"
```

Thank you all very much for your assistance!